# DDD aware of existance of an entity outside the context?

Tags: domain-driven-design

In my journey to try to learn DDD, I came with a simple problem.
I have an aggregate root Assistant.
That assistant can manage therapists.

so I have:

```
var assistant = GetAssistant(Id);
var therapist = new Therapist("john@doe.com");
assistant.Manage(therapist);
repository.Save(assistant);
```

the business rules says that if the therapist john@doe.com is already managed by any assistant, then it cannot be added.

But as far as I understand, assistant doesn't have to know about the therapists of other assistants. So how can I make this in DDD?

**UDATE**
Therapist is Entity.
Assistant is Entity.

Assistant must be a user in the system.
Therapist *may* be a user in the system.

A therapist has a schedule and create appointments, etc, but also can have an assistant that does that work for her/him.

There can be an assistant as a user that manage other therapist (users or not).

So the entry to the system is by registering a User.
Then, you can add a Therapist (yourself or another)
If you add another therapist for you to manage, I want to be sure that:
a) Therapist doesn't already exist on the system.

I think I got my AR all wrong. But if my user is the AR, I face the same issue were how can a user know about other data from the system that is supposed to not know?

I really appreciate your help, I'm banging my head hard with this.

Comment: john@doe.com is just created, how could he be managed by other assistant? Can a therapist identified by 'john@doe.com'?

Comment: 2 posible reasons: 1. Assistant A adds john@doe.com. 2 Assistant B adds john@doe.com. OR Therapist john@doe.com register himself. Have in mind that john@doe.com doesn't have to be a user in the system. It's not an account registration.

Comment: The current code looks like: The Therapist is a value object which is not identifiable. But Your examples seem to tell: The Therapist is identifiable. What about making Therapist an aggregate root. And let it be managed by Assistant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the implementation point of view. You may write the code as:

```
var assistant = GetAssistant(Id);
var therapist = GetTherapist("john@doe.com");
therapist.ManagedBy(assistant);
repository.Save(therapist);
```

The therapist knows if he/she is managed by an assistant, so the rule is applied here. And the therapist can handle concurrency contention with locks.

On the other side, the therapist may not exist yet. I think this is more a UI convenience concern (find or create issue).

Comment: oh god, you made it look so simple. I like it a lot. I will try to fit into my design and see how it goes. thanks! Those GetX I suppose comes from ReadModels, right?

Comment: GetAssistant may comes from ReadModels, but GetTherapist should comes from write models. As only the write models represents the truth in your application. So you if want to modify them, you'd better depend on the "true data".

Comment: Ok, so Therapist is an Aggregate Root. got it! I'll let you know how it worked out. thanks again for your time, very useful information!

Comment: Optimistic locking would probably be more suitable than pessimistic locking.